# Inline-block elements within a fixed width container

Tags: html, css, whitespace

How can I make two elements that are `inline-block` fit within a fixed width?

I don't necessarily know the width of the first element, and the second, longer, element (with `white-space: nowrap`) takes the width of the fixed element, so overflows the container.

```
/---------------------/
/Label: |Other content/ that just  |
/       |keeps going a/nd overflows|
/---------------------/
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj8evrqr/)

```css
.fixed-width-container{
    border: 1px red solid;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.inline-block-1{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px blue solid;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.inline-block-2{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width-container">
    <div class="inline-block-1">Label:</div>
    <div class="inline-block-2">Some really long text that is going to go down to the next line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both worked, but my label was actually two words that I wanted to remain on the same line, so the floating kept them together, while the table-cell made it line break. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bigger fan of the float-overflow trick.

Change the css to this:

```
.fixed-width-container{
    border: 1px red solid; /* Get rid of white space rule */
    width: 200px;
}
.inline-block-1{
    float: left;
    border: 1px blue solid;
}
.inline-block-2{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also, I would suggest using css class names that don't rely on "inline-block" in the name. If you ever need to change the display to something else (block, table-cell, etc.) it could get confusing.

Comment: Oh, definitely - the class names were just for clarity in the example.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. This is supported by all modern browsers (and [IE > 7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)), and it isn't a float hack.

```css
.fixed-width-container{
    border: 1px red solid;
    width: 200px;
    display: table;
}
.inline-block-1{
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px blue solid;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.inline-block-2{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width-container">
    <div class="inline-block-1">Label word:</div>
    <div class="inline-block-2">Some really long text that is going to go down to the next line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My label was two words, so this caused a line break, which I didn't want. Otherwise, worked perfectly!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just had to add `white-space:nowrap` to `.inline-block-1`.